# How do I stop end="" after all the integers have been combined?

Tags: python, string, ord

I want end="" to stop after it has removed all the spaces between integers.

The result I get is this:

```
106111104110word
```

but I want to get this:

```
106111104110
word
```

Code:

```
name = 'john' 

for char in name:
    print(ord(char), end="")
print("word")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store your answer in a variable, and then print. Other answers in this thread work too, but this way you can also use the result.

```
name = 'john' 
result = ""

for char in name:
    result += str(ord(char))

print(result)
print("word")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `\n` in your code:

```py
name = 'john' 

for char in name:
    print(ord(char), end="")
print("\nword")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
name = 'john' 

for char in name:
    print(ord(char), end="")
print()
print("word")
```

Answer (score 0):

name = 'john'
result = ""

for char in name:
result += str(ord(char))

print(result) `println()
print("word")

or you can use /n :

- List item

')

Comment: You have to put your code in a suitable tag